# Angular loading spinner with [hidden] does not update

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular material loading spinner in my program that is shown while a REST API is called. When the promise resolves, the `visible` variable gets set to `false` and the spinner should disappear.

[image]

My problem is that the spinner does not update when it is set to false again. I have to manually trigger a tooltip over a button or something, and only then does the page hide the spinner.

I know for a fact that the variable gets set correctly, but the page does not update the spinner state when it should disappear. Appearing works correctly.

Is the problem that the state is set and unset in the same function?

Here's the template

```
<div [hidden]="!visible" class="row justify-content-center">
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

When I click the update button, `this.visible = true;` is called.
Then, an http service gets called:

```
this.httpService.getData(data).then(receivedData => {
    [...]
    this.visible = false;    // this is called correctly, but does not change the visibility.
```

But the spinner is still there, together with all the graphs that have been drawn now:

[image]

How can I fix this? The spinner should not be visible anymore, but it only disappears after I hover over a button or some other element.

Comment: Why don't you use `*ngIf="visible"` or `[style.display]="visible ? 'block' : 'none'"`  instead of `[hidden]="!visible"` ? `ngIf` will destroy the component and remove it from the DOM, `style.display` will hide it using CSS

Comment: I tried all those and the same thing happens. It only updates after I hover the mouse over a button or do some other actions, but the spinner remains forever if I don't.

Comment: Could you please show more code? The issue is difficult to pinpoint at the moment, and everyone is left to guesswork.

Comment: ist the change detection disabled (https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) ?

Comment: you are using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush ?

Comment: @AakashGarg I am, in fact... thanks. This appears to be the problem. I'll try to fix this. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe using OnPush Strategy in your component. Inject ChangeDetectorRef and try calling detectChanges method of it.

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted my changeDetection to default and now it works as expected.

Comment: I do have a related problem now: the spinner animation restarts a lot and looks like it's "jumping". This does not happen onPush. The animation is probably restarted a lot. How can I help this?

Comment: that's what i said. don't remove on push. just call detectChanges after you set visible to false.

Comment: Unfortunately, both `detectChanges` and `markForCheck` does not work.

Comment: give fix width and height to div inside which spinner is there.